# Grabbing a Soundcloud Image

Tags: php, javascript, image, curl, soundcloud

Is it possible to grab the image URL of a Soundcloud Track Art using only Javascript & PHP?

Can the same process be done to grabbing the download link of a Soundcloud Track?

Any help is greatly appreciated!  :)

Comment: Well, you can start here http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check here http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks
there is property called `artwork_url`